# io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl cannot be cast to io.restassured.response.ResponseOptions

Tags: post, response, serenity-bdd

Somedays back this below line of code used to work and I was getting the response. Now, it gives error as

> java.lang.classCastException:io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl
>   cannot be cast to io.restassured.response.ResponseOptions

Below is my code which used to work earlier and now it doesn't work:-

```
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner;
import net.serenitybdd.rest.SerenityRest;

static Response response;

public void createAI(){

response = SerenityRest.given().urlEncodingEnabled(false).contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .auth().oauth2(authToken)
            .log().all()
            .when().body(JsonData)
            .post("/myAccount/category/AI/create")
            .then().extract().response();

    System.out.println(response.asString());
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks community.. This code solved my problem:-

```
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner;
import net.serenitybdd.rest.SerenityRest;

static Response response;

public void createAI(){

response = SerenityRest.given().urlEncodingEnabled(false).relaxedHTTPSValidation().contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .auth().oauth2(authToken)
            .log().all()
            .when().body(JsonData)
            .post("/myAccount/category/AI/create")
            .then().log().all().extract().response();

    }
```